# remove key(s) from a json array under javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Need to remove key(s) from a json array under javascript (jquery).
Looks like my code is wong although it was working in my Chrome console.
Your help is the most welcome.
Jacques

```js
function test() {
  var json = {
    "ID": "2196",
    "VERSION": "1-2022",
    "FILE": "2196.docx"
  };
  json = JSON.stringify(json)
  console.log("json " + json);

  delete json['FILE'];
  console.log("json " + json);
  return;
}

test();
```

Comment: You can't delete from JSON, you have to delete from the original object before stringifying, or parse the JSON, delete the key, then stringify again.

Comment: Well you could delete it from a string as well (with some different code), but I'd say deleting it from the object is way better and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `stringify` the object before removing the key.

```js
function test() {
  var json = {
    "ID": "2196",
    "VERSION": "1-2022",
    "FILE": "2196.docx"
  };
  // stringify to show in console as string
  json = JSON.stringify(json)
  console.log("json " + json);

  // convert back to object so you can remove the key
  json = JSON.parse(json);
  delete json['FILE'];
  
  // stringify to show new object in console as string
  json = JSON.stringify(json);
  console.log("json " + json);
  return;
}

test();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the use of stringify. Afterwards it makes sense. Thanks to you Folks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify has an often overlooked parameter called the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter). It can accept an array of key names to include in the json output:

```
 JSON.stringify(data, ["ID","VERSION"], " ");  // FILE is excluded
```

**Snippet**

Run the snippet to see the output with and without using the replacer.

```js
let data = {
  "ID": "2196",
  "VERSION": "1-2022",
  "FILE": "2196.docx"
};

console.log("Without replacer: ",
  JSON.stringify(data, null, " ")
);

console.log("Using replacer: ",
  JSON.stringify(data, ["ID","VERSION"], " ")
);
```